# Ошибка в боте для telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для telegram, в одном из условных операторов, нужно проверять условие не только на совпадение слова, но и на значение переменной. Но при указании переменной почему-то возникает ошибка, что переменная не объявлена. Не могли бы подсказать, как это исправить.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def action_3(messege):
if messege.chat.type == 'private':
    if messege.text == 'Ощупать условие1':
        bot.send_message(messege.chat.id, "текст")
        flag = 1
        bot.register_next_step_handler(messege, action_3)
    elif messege.text == 'условие1' and flag == 1 and flag1 == 1:
        bot.send_message(messege.chat.id, 'текст')
    elif messege.text == 'условие2':
        bot.send_message(messege.chat.id, 'текст2')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(messege, action_3)
        flag1 = 1
    else:
        bot.send_message(messege.chat.id, "Я вас не расслышал")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(messege, action_3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задайте переменную flag = 0 и flag1 = 0 где-то перед использыванием, и когда будете менять переменную сделайте её в global, тогда должно все работать